# 'table was not locked with lock tables' when executing a nested SQL while the table is already locked

Tags: mysql

I was tring to execute following sql, because of sychoronization between multiple processes, I locked the table first

```
lock tables Report write;
SELECT id,taskTime,timeout,maxExecutionTimes,currentOwner, tenantID, 
case when tenantID = 'NoValue' then 1 else 0 end tenantOrder, 
case when tenantID in (select distinct tenantID from Report where state = 2) then 1 else 0 end mspInHandling 
FROM Report WHERE state=2 and maxExecutionTimes>executionTimes  
order by tenantOrder desc, mspInHandling limit 1
```

While the table is already locked, this sql statement always gives me a error like: "table Report was not locked with lock tables"

**If I don't lock tables, the SQL statment can run well**, I think it might be something related to the nested (`select distinct tenantID from Report where state = 2`), but was not able to find a way out.

Can someone help upon this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a subquery you need to alias the subquery table and lock that table using the same alias. Could you try this?:

```
lock tables Report write, Report as r2 read;
SELECT id,taskTime,timeout,maxExecutionTimes,currentOwner, tenantID, 
case when tenantID = 'NoValue' then 1 else 0 end tenantOrder, 
case when tenantID in (select distinct tenantID from Report as r2 where state = 2) then 1 else 0 end mspInHandling 
FROM Report WHERE state=2 and maxExecutionTimes>executionTimes  
order by tenantOrder desc, mspInHandling limit 1
```

In the above sql, I am locking table `Report as r2 read` and aliasing the subquery `Report as r2`

[reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I need a write lock to provide sychoronization between processes. Looks like in mysql, as long as you lock a table for write, you can not read from other tables, while in this sql statement, the nested query may result in a temp table, and if is not locked, therefore result in an error. I have tried "lock tables Report read, Report AS Report1 write;" suggestion without getting to to work, does this mean there is no way to run such statement after a table locking?

Comment: @KeanLiu ah yes your right it creates a temp table that needs to be locked with the table alias you used to lock. I think the subquery table may need to be locked with `write`. I'll update answer now